# Convert ShuffleRDD with nested strcture to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a nested structure as follows:

```
("key1", List[("home", "abc", "06794")])
("key1", List[("work", "sdcsdc", "06794")])
("key1", List[("home2", "adssd", "06794")])
```

I want to convert it to a concatenated list as follows:

```
("key1", List[("home", "abc", "06794"), ("work", "sdcsdc", "06794"), ("home2", "adssd", "06794")])
```

I was able to do so by converting the df to rdd using:

```
val a = df.rdd.map { case Row(k, v) => (k, List(v)) }
val myRdd = a.reduceByKey((x,y) => List(x,y).flatten)
```

However, now I am unable to convert this rdd back to a df. I have tried the following approaches and none of them seem to work.

- convert using toDF(), this is unable to determine the schema

  ```
  myRdd.toDF()
  ```
- convert using case classes, this gives class not found error:

  ```
  case class myData(keyColumn: String, addressed: List[address])
  case class address(description: String, address: String, zip: String)
  myRdd.map{(k,v) => myData(k,v)}.toDF()
  ```

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Could you post actual data? It is not exactly clear what are the types here.

Comment: df.rdd results look like this:  ((90, [home,21 mount st, 06778]), (133, [work,69 mount st, 06778]), (90, [home,2 claire st, 06778]), (133, [work,69 claire st, 06778]))

Comment: Could you show at least the schema? (`printSchema`)?

Comment: root |-- keyColumn: string (nullable = true) |-- address: array (nullable = true) | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) | | |-- description: string (nullable = true) | | |-- address: string (nullable = true) | | |-- zip: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 1):

If won't even ask how you get this structure. For starters lets group and flatten rows:

```
val combined = df
  .map(r => (r.getAs[String]("keyColumn"), r.getAs[Seq[Row]]("address")))
  .groupByKey
  .map{case (k, vs) => Row(k, vs.flatten)}
```

All whats left is to `createDataFrame`:

```
val transformed = sqlContext.createDataFrame(combined, df.schema)
```

Comment: BTW its pretty slow, am thinking coz of the groupByKey. I was trying to use reduceBy Key instead. Any pointers for that.

Comment: There is no reason to use `reduceByKey` here. It won't reduce amount of data to be transfered and will increase GC pressure.

Comment: oh ok.. Any other pointers on how I can improve the performance here.

Comment: Not really. This is simply an expensive operation and passing data between DF and RDD doesn't make it better.

Comment: Is there a better way to merge this find of data?

Comment: One way or another you have to shuffle all the data. If requirement is this exact output then there is no way around it.

Comment: Would it be better if I sorted the data based on the key & partitioned it by key column?